# Mysql : adding days to a date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table (mytable) with this data:

```
CORTE_DATE ;   FECHA_INICIO
2013-03-31 ; 2012-12-31 00:00:00.0
2013-06-30 ; 2013-03-31 00:00:00.0
2013-09-30 ; 2013-06-30 00:00:00.0
2013-12-31 ; 2013-09-30 00:00:00.0
```

I am trying to add one (1) day to FECHA_INICIO field, I have tried several ways:

```
update mytable set FECHA_INICIO = ADDDATE(FECHA_INICIO, 1);
update mytable set FECHA_INICIO = DATE_ADD(FECHA_INICIO, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
update mytable set FECHA_INICIO = FECHA_INICIO + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

and all of them update FECHA_INICIO with NULL. If I select the rows like the following:

```
select adddate(FECHA_INICIO, interval 1 day) FECHA, FECHA_INICIO from mytable
```

I get the following

```
    FECHA   FECHA_INICIO
(null)  2012-12-31 00:00:00.0
(null)  2013-03-31 00:00:00.0
(null)  2013-06-30 00:00:00.0
(null)  2013-09-30 00:00:00.0
```

I am using mysql 5.1.69 under linux

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a mysql settings problem?

---

Now I found out why... using a mysql console, I made a select of mytable, and look what I got:

```
+------------+--------------+
| FECHA      | FECHA_INICIO |
+------------+--------------+
| 2013-03-31 | 2013-01-00   |
| 2013-06-30 | 2013-04-00   |
| 2013-09-30 | 2013-07-00   |
| 2013-12-31 | 2013-10-00   |
+------------+--------------+
```

So the problem was in the date it was stored at the column. I was using DbVisualizer to do the selects, and the driver returned a different date.

Comment: That extra `.0` at the end of your date tells me it is not a valid date format and that column is probably stored as a string. Use `STR_TO_DATE` on that column before doing date math on it.

Comment: What's the datatype of `FECHA_INICIO` column?

Comment: May be the datatype of FECHA_INICIO is varchar or char.

Comment: Sorry , the FECHA_INCIO column is a datetime: CREATE 
    TABLE mytable 
    ( 
        CORTE_DATE date NOT NULL, 
        FECHA_INICIO datetime, 
        PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (CORTE_DATE) 
    ) 
    ENGINE= InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET= latin1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I go by your create table schema as posted by you in comment then everything is working fine. There must be something else wrong.

See this fiddle here. As you can see both `update` and `select` working as expected.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dedcf/2

Comment: I found out that if I use another column (fecha) it works fine... something's odd around.

Answer (score 0):

If i run following query :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( "2012-12-31 00:00:00.0", INTERVAL 1
DAY )
```

It give me right output:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/20935

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE mytable set 
FECHA_INICIO = 
DATE_ADD('2013-03-31 00:00:00' , INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: This is working, but I will have to do it row by row. It seems to be a mysql settings problem, because I have tried in other databases, and it works fine.

Comment: instead of giving a hard code date take **FECHA_INICIO** like this `update mytable set 
FECHA_INICIO = ADDDATE(FECHA_INICIO, INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out why... using a mysql console, I made a select of mytable, and look what I got:

```
+------------+--------------+
| FECHA      | FECHA_INICIO |
+------------+--------------+
| 2013-03-31 | 2013-01-00   |
| 2013-06-30 | 2013-04-00   |
| 2013-09-30 | 2013-07-00   |
| 2013-12-31 | 2013-10-00   |
+------------+--------------+
```

So the problem was in the date it was stored at the column. I was using DbVisualizer to do the selects, and the driver returned a diferent date.

Thanks for you time.